# on change route need to run a function to check the token

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

In Angular, for every route that has been changed, I need to run the function if the valid token is set or not.

Can anyone help me to do this?

In Angular 1 I use to do using `$on`.

Comment: I can't understand what you want, do you want to run a function as soon as a route is changed ?

Comment: this thing is already mentioned in this thread mate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042965/change-component-content-on-route-changes-angular-2/43043413#43043413

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CanActivate` to guard routes or call a function during transition of routes , example is mentioned below

```
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private router: Router) { }

canActivate() {
  return true //or false
}
}
```

For official [doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html)

**Updated Steps**:

1. write the AuthGuard Service as mentioned in the above code
2. Add the AuthGaurd in providers (app.module.ts file)
3. In this way whenever transition occurs canActivate is called.

**Assumptions**

1. You already have registered the routes with appModule

**Tutorial**

1. http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial

Comment: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial

Comment: since today i started it, i know i am asking silly thing, but can you tell me where update the code means in which file, since i need to check on every route change

Comment: Please review the updated answer , Most welcome to ask again . Accept the answer if you think it is right .